# Show x-Axis line but hide all data points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want the second datetime x-Axis to show, but I want none of the points from that series to be visible. I just want the x-Axis line. How can I do this?

```
 Highcharts.chart("container", {
      chart: {
        type: "line",
      },
      xAxis: [
        {
          type: "category"
        },
        {
          type: "datetime",
        }
      ]
    });
```

https://codepen.io/austeng/pen/mdJrRRm

[image: Graph]

Edit: I want the black line to be gone, but I want to keep the Date x-Axis line. The black line are the points from the date x-Axis. I just the date x-Axis grid line to show... not the points associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: [],
```

I hope it helps if you want something like as below!! 
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can't seem to figure out how this would apply to my question. Could you edit my codepen?

Comment: Check out the image I have attached. Isn't this what you asked?

Comment: See the edited answer. That's what I deduced from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good solution for your requirements is to use the second series which will be a null series, but with defined **pointStart**, **pointInterval** and is attached to the second yAxis, which is hidden.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b0j5o7Lw/

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
    }
  },
```

and

```
   {
      yAxis: 1,
      type: 'column',
      name: "Date",
      data: [
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

      ],
      xAxis: 1,
      showInLegend: false,
    }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart